# How to achieve code reusability in Quarto Markdown (qmd) similar to R Markdown's chunk reusability?

Tags: r-markdown, quarto

I am attempting to render Quarto markdown (qmd), and in my qmd file, I aim to reuse a code chunk multiple times. Specifically, I wish to execute a code cell with the label `label: package-import` without displaying its code (i.e. `echo: false`) for the initial call, but then reuse the code cell to exhibit the commands in a subsequent code cell (i.e. `echo: true`). This concept is inspired by the implementation of chunk reusability in R Markdown, as elucidated in [14.1 Reuse code chunks | R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/reuse-chunks.html#reuse-chunks). However, the means of reusing the code cell described in [14.1.2 Use the same chunk label in another chunk](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/reuse-chunks.html#same-label) and [14.1.3 Use reference labels (*)](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/reuse-chunks.html#ref-label) are not available when employing qmd. Is there an equivalent feature in qmd that allows for code reusability similar to what is possible in R Markdown?

## MWE-same-chunk-label.qmd

To replicate [14.1.2 Use the same chunk label in another chunk](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/reuse-chunks.html#same-label) using Quarto

````
```{python}
# | echo: false
# | eval: true
# | label: packcage-import

import os
import session_info
```

```{python}
import session_info

session_info.show()
```

```{python}
# | echo: true
# | eval: false
# | label: packcage-import
```
````

> ERROR: Cell label names must be unique (found duplicate '#packcage-import')

## MWE-use-in-another-chunk.qmd

To replicate [14.1.3 Use reference labels (*)](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/reuse-chunks.html#ref-label) using Quarto

````
```{python}
# | echo: false
# | eval: true
# | label: packcage-import

import os
import session_info
```

```{python}
import session_info

session_info.show()
```

```{python}
# | ref.label="packcage-import"
```
````

> Starting python3 kernel...Done
>
> Executing 'experiment.ipynb'
>
> Cell 1/3...Done
>
> Cell 2/3...Done
>
> Cell 3/3...ERROR:
>
> None of the known patterns match for ref.label="packcage-import"

Comment: The issue is not about quarto. It's about the engine. From the output I guess you are using the `jupyter` engine. But the features or chunk options you want to use are only available with the `knitr` engine, i.e. the code from the RMarkdown Cookbook works fine in quarto when using `engine: knitr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stefan pointed out in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76278117/how-to-achieve-code-reusability-in-quarto-markdown-qmd-similar-to-r-markdowns#comment134512695_76278117), setting `engine: knitr` in the YAML section of the qmd file is the key solution. Also, it is necessary to install R, [`rmarkdown`](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/), and [`reticulate`](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) for the rendering of the qmd.

Somehow, the method described in [14.1.2 Use the same chunk label in another chunk](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/reuse-chunks.html#same-label) only works in my environment.

````
---
engine: knitr
---

```{python}
# | echo: false
# | eval: true
# | label: packcage-import

import os
import session_info
```

```{python}
import session_info

session_info.show()
```

```{python}
# | echo: true
# | eval: false
# | label: packcage-import
```
````

Comment: If you want to follow this pattern of code reusing (`echo: true` & `eval: false` in first case and then the vice versa in second case), another hack (not quite a solution in my opinion) would be writing a lua filter that would copy the code content in the second case and should work regardless of engine!

Comment: @shafee Thank you for your comment. Would you want to add an answer proposing the lua filter you mentioned? As I am not used to writing my own lua filters, your example will help me so much.

Answer (score 3):

As I have mentioned in my comment, you can mimic the pattern of code reusing in R-markdown somewhat closer in Quarto using Lua filter. So I am proposing the following solution (I do not think its a good solution though).

````
---
title: Code Reuse in Quarto
format: html
jupyter: python3
filters: 
  - code-reuse.lua
---

```{python}
#| classes: hide-all
#| label: package-import

import os
```

```{.python ref-label="package-import"}
```

```{.python ref-label="package-import"}
```

```{python}
#| label: testing
#| classes: hide-code

def greetings():
  print("Hello from python")
  
greetings()
```

```{.python ref-label="testing"}
```
````

There are a couple of things to note,

- To reuse a previously written chunk, use non-executable code block syntax (i.e. `{.python}`) along the with `ref-label` attribute (note the equal sign `=` is used, not `:`). The value of `ref-label` would be the chunk label that you want to use.
- And most importantly, to reuse a chunk, it must be `echo`-ed. If you use `echo: false`, lua filter could not get the content of this chunk. But to get same behavior as `echo: false`, I have used two classes, `hide-all` will hide all the code in chunk along with output and `hide-code` will hide only the chunk code, not the output.
- Also note that you can not execute the reused chunk obviously, since all of these code-copying by lua filter is happening after the jupyter notebook or any engine completes executing. So only the original chunk is being executed. So using `eval: true` or `eval: false` is unnecessary!.

**code-reuse.lua**

```
str = pandoc.utils.stringify

local function get_code(code)
  return {
    CodeBlock = function(cb)
      if cb.classes:includes('cell-code') then
        code["content"] = cb.text
      end
      return cb
    end
  }
end


local function collect_cb_labels(collection)
  return {
    Div = function(el)
      local code = {}
      el:walk(get_code(code))
      content_table = {
        ["label"] = el.identifier,
        ["code_content"] = code["content"]
      }
      table.insert(collection, content_table)
    end
  }
end


local function reuse_code(collection)
  return {
    CodeBlock = function(cb)
      local ref = cb.attributes["ref-label"]
      if ref then
        for key, val in ipairs(collection) do
          if (str(val.label) == str(ref)) then
            cb.text = val.code_content
            return cb
          end
        end
      end
    end
  }
end
 
 
local function hide_code()
  return {
    CodeBlock = function(cb)
      if cb.classes:includes('cell-code') then
        return pandoc.Null()
      end
    end
  }
end


local function check_visibility()
  return {
    Div = function(el) 
      if el.classes:includes('hide-all') then
        return pandoc.Null()
      elseif el.classes:includes('hide-code') then
        return el:walk(hide_code())
      end
    end
  }
end


function Pandoc(doc)
  local collection = {}
  doc:walk(collect_cb_labels(collection))
  local doc = doc:walk(reuse_code(collection))
  return doc:walk(check_visibility())
end
```

---

[image]

Comment: Apologies for my delayed response, but I am grateful to see the solution using Lua filters! I have upvoted your answer; however, the Lua filter may not be suitable for my current use case. In my current project, I wish to avoid altering the notation of the code block (e.g., `{python}` -> `{.python}`; `: ` -> `=`) and maintain the customizability of the `echo` and `eval` options. Nonetheless, your solution will undoubtedly be valuable for others and my future work!!